# parsing xml with php generates error for street names with apostrophes

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse xml using php.  I establish a connection to the database and try to fetch rows with php and then fed them into xml markers for a google map.  I have a problem with streets that have an apostrophe in the name (e.g. Charles de Gaulle'a):

```
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

print "<markers>\n";

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

    $location = "<mar ";
    $location .= ' LGT=' . "'" . (str_replace(',', '.', $row['Longtitude'])) . "'";
    $location .= ' LAT=' . "'" . (str_replace(',', '.', $row['Latitude'])) . "'";
    $location .= ' STREET=' . "'" . ($row['STREET']) . "'";
    $location .= " />\n";
    $output = $location;

    print ($output);
}
print "</markers>\n";
```

This works fine when there are no streets with apostrophes inside, but with this street it returns an error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://mywebsite.com/parsexml.php
Line Number 5178, Column 141:
```

Question is how can I fix it so that no xml parsing error is returned and the markers are generated without any problems.

Thank you

Comment: Generally, try to avoid serializing XML "by hand" - it's too easy to get it wrong. I don't know the PHP environment well enough to know what library to recommend, but you should use a library for this rather than doing it yourself, just as you should always use a library for XML parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use htmlentities() to encode your data. Changing your quotes will just cause problems when the other quote is used. You should always use htmlentities().

Comment: can you provide tutorial or even better example with my code?  Then I'll mark your answer as correct one.

Comment: Change `($row['STREET'])` to `(htmlentities($row['STREET'], ENT_QUOTES ))`

Comment: Nigel has nailed it but to be really careful for what you want to achieve: $location .= ' STREET=' . "'" . (htmlentities($row['STREET'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1 ) . "'"; This way you can put all sorts of crazy symbols in your data even < and >

Comment: If you always use the mysql_real_escape_string() function when inserting data and always use htmlentities() when displaying data you can just sit there and watch evil users try to inject evil SQL and JavaScript all day long and fail every time

Comment: It works now, but there is a problem with places with no street.  Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: What sort of problem? Parsing?

Comment: Maybe?: $location .= ' STREET=' . "'" . (htmlentities(($row['STREET']=''?'None':$row['STREET']), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1 ) . "'";

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the quotes are the same as round the attribute, you where ending up with `STREET='Charles de Gaulle'a'`, so change them to " instead of '...

```
$location .= ' STREET="' . ($row['STREET']) . '"';
```

There may be instances though where other characters cause problems, but this should solve your immediate problem.

It would be better if you had this as an actual entity in itself (rather than an attribute), which would solve most issues.  So...

```
<Street>Charles de Gaulle'a</Street>
```

Comment: Thank you it works for this particular street, but it generates problems for street names with " in the name.